# Performance of reading every time from a concurrent hashmap vs. assigning a value to a variable then using it

Tags: java, multithreading, performance

Code 1:

```
listModel.getStockList().forEach((contractName, v) -> {
    if (listModel.getContractDetails().get(contractName).getAskPrice() >
            listModel.getArchieveContractDetails().get(contractName).getHighPrice()
            && validatorUtils.checkOrderValidity1(Action.BRAC_ORDER_1, contractName)) {
        method1(listModel.getContractDetails().get(contractName).getAskPrice());
        method2(0, listModel.getContractDetails().get(contractName).getAskPrice());
        syso(listModel.getContractDetails().get(contractName).getAskPrice());
    }

});
```

Code 2:

```
listModel.getStockList().forEach((contractName, v) -> {
    int askPrice = listModel.getContractDetails().get(contractName).getAskPrice();
    if (askPrice > listModel.getArchieveContractDetails().get(contractName).getHighPrice()
            && validatorUtils.checkOrderValidity1(Action.BRAC_ORDER_1, contractName)) {
        method1(askPrice);
        method2(0, askPrice);
        syso(askPrice);
    }
});
```

In code 1, I am reading `price` directly from `getaskPrice()`; and in code 2, I used an `askPrice` variable.

Which approach will give me better performance and why ?

Comment: It doesn't matter (for now) which one performs better. The question is: what's better readable? (I personally would have stored `listModel.getArchieveContractDetails().get(contractName).getHighPrice()` into a variable, so the if statement ecomes better readable.)

Comment: You have tagged the question as "multithreading". Is this code being run while the `listModel` is being updated? This can make both fragments behave differently! Otherwise, why is the question tagged "multithreading"? What is going on in other threads?

Comment: @tucuxi..Yes..The other thread updates the askPrice

Answer (score 0):

Well, storing the result of `get` in a variable and then using the variable multiple times should **definitely** never be any worse, performance-wise, than repeating the `get` multiple times.  Whereas the `Hashmap` implementation **might, or might not**, perform comparably well on multiple `get`s of the same key.

But consider that **you** are in **complete control** of how **you write** your Java code, but you **are not** necessarily in control of how good the `HashMap` implementation is where your Java code runs.

Seems better to err on the side of caution and take control over the things you have control over (i.e., **do** write your Java code to save the result of `get` to be reused multiple times), rather than hope for the best in things you have little or no control over (i.e., **don't** expect you'll always be running on a JDK with a "good" `HashMap` implementation).